# How to Change Date of Datetimepicker control to persian in win 7 using C#.net

Tags: c#, windows-10, datetimepicker, persian-calendar

I am developing desktop application in C#.I use Datetimepicker in personel form  to insert datetime into table so in win 10 datetimepicker is in persian date and it is ok but in win 7 the date of datetimepicker is gregorian .So help me to change the date in 7 to persian for datetimepicker control .

[datetimepicker in win 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9LNb.jpg)

[datetimepicker in win 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYhft.png)

Answer (score 2):

download a separated  component for Persian date picker 
see the below link : 
http://video-learn.net/post/267

also ther is full component for Persian tools at below link :

https://www.sourcebaran.com/%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%84%D9%88%D8%AF-11-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%BE%D9%88%D9%86%D9%86%D8%AA-%D9%85%D9%81%DB%8C%D8%AF-%D9%88-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%AF%DB%8C-%D9%88%DB%8C%DA%98%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84.html